# Is there any good article about .NET configuration system?

Tags: .net

Just want to get a thorough understanding of **.NET configuration system** in a short time. Any recommendations would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking for .NET in general, not including specifics for ASP.NET? Or are you looking for ASP.NET info moreso specifically?

Comment: What is ".NET configuration system"?

Comment: I mean things related to app.config, web.config. i.e. configurations approaches used by .NET applications.

Comment: This looks answered, what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from MSDN - try

http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-AspNet-Tutorial-27.aspx

There are a series of tutorials. Try the answer to this question:

[Is there an in depth guide to application configuration for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751817/is-there-an-in-depth-guide-to-application-configuration-for-net)

Answer (score 0):

A quite good article for the beginning: [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx). Sadly there is no deep, detailed and good description for all possibilities of standard configuration. Actually it is very capable and configurable, but many things can only be discovered via [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) and similar tools, because msdn documentation is sometimes confusing and lacks good examples.